# Python 3 - Avoid Instances from sharing or overwritting attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

First, I use the Numpy's array creation function 'full' (such array is an attribute of the Graph class), the entire array has instances of the Vertex class, and each Vertex has an attribute of coordinates named 'coordsXY' (which is a list, where Index 0 stores the X position and Index 1 stores the Y position).

```
import numpy as np

class Vertex:

   def __init__(self):
       self.coordsXY = [0, 0]

class Graph:

   def __init__(self):
       self.vArray = np.full((8, 8), fill_value=Vertex(), dtype=np.object_)

       for i in range(0, 8):
           print(" ")
           for j in range(0, 8):
               self.vArray[i][j].coordsXY[0] = i
               self.vArray[i][j].coordsXY[1] = j

               print(self.vArray[i][j].coordsXY, end=" ")

       for m in range(0, 8):
           print(" ")
           for n in range(0, 8):
               print(self.vArray[m][n].coordsXY, end=" ")
```

And everything is alright at the first 2 FOR loops:

```
[0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2] [0, 3] [0, 4] [0, 5] [0, 6] [0, 7]  
[1, 0] [1, 1] [1, 2] [1, 3] [1, 4] [1, 5] [1, 6] [1, 7]  
[2, 0] [2, 1] [2, 2] [2, 3] [2, 4] [2, 5] [2, 6] [2, 7]  
[3, 0] [3, 1] [3, 2] [3, 3] [3, 4] [3, 5] [3, 6] [3, 7]  
[4, 0] [4, 1] [4, 2] [4, 3] [4, 4] [4, 5] [4, 6] [4, 7]  
[5, 0] [5, 1] [5, 2] [5, 3] [5, 4] [5, 5] [5, 6] [5, 7]  
[6, 0] [6, 1] [6, 2] [6, 3] [6, 4] [6, 5] [6, 6] [6, 7]  
[7, 0] [7, 1] [7, 2] [7, 3] [7, 4] [7, 5] [7, 6] [7, 7]
```

But at the second 2 FOR loops:

```
[7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7]
[7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7]
[7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7]
[7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7]
[7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7]
[7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7]
[7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7]
[7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7] [7, 7]
```

The coordsXY attribute of every instance of the Vertex instantly gets overwritten by the value of the attribute of the last Vertex of the array; what could I do to stop it from doing that?

Comment: Your `fill` command created one `Vertex()` object, and put a reference to that in all slots of the array.  If you want a different object in each slot, you have create each one individually.

Comment: Why are you putting these objects into numpy arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (not tested):

```
class Vertex:

   def __init__(self, i, j):
       self.coordsXY = [i,j]
   def __repr__(self):
       return str(self.coordsXY)

class Graph:

   def __init__(self):
       self.vArray = np.empty((8,8), dtype=object)

       for i in range(0, 8):
           for j in range(0, 8):
               self.vArray[i,j] = Vertex(i,j)

print(Graph())
```

This creates a new `Vertex` object for each slot of the array.  And since `Vertex` has a `repr`, the display should be nice.

A list equivalent

```
graph = []
for i in range(8):
    row = []
    for j in range(8):
         row.append(Vertex(i,j))
    graph.append(row)

print(graph)
print(np.array(graph))
```

Your `full` was the equivalent to `[[Vertex(0,0)]*8]*8`

Answer (score 0):

As hpaulj said in a comment, you are creating one `Vertex` object and filling the array with references to that one object, rather than having different objects in each slot. It's actually overwriting the values in both sets of for-loops, it's just that in the first set, you're printing each value before it gets overwritten.

An improvement on hpaulj's answer:

```
class Vertex:    
   def __init__(self, i, j):
       self.coordsXY = [i,j]
   def __repr__(self):
       return str(self.coordsXY)

class Graph:    
   def __init__(self, size = 8):
       self.vArray = np.array(
               [
                   [Vertex(i,j) for j in range(size)]
                   for i in range(size)
               ]
           )
```